# Filtering noise of unknown variance

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, stochastic-filtering

Say that there is an unknown state $\theta\in \{0,1\}$ with prior $p_t$ (that state is 1) and we observe a "discrete" realization of the signal
$$ dY_t = \sigma_\theta dW_t$$
meaning that we observe $dY$ for $dt$ units of time. By standard bayes rule
$$ p_{t+dt} = \frac{p_t \frac{1}{\sigma_1} \phi(\frac{dY}{\sigma_1 dt^{1/2}})}{p_t \frac{1}{\sigma_1} \phi(\frac{dY}{\sigma_1 dt^{1/2}}) + (1-p_t) \frac{1}{\sigma_0} \phi(\frac{dY}{\sigma_0 dt^{1/2}})}$$

where $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(\frac{1}{2}x^2)$ is a standard normal density. With some manipulations we get the loglikelyhood $\ell_{t}= \log(\frac{p_t}{1-p_t})$ satifies

$$d \ell_t = \log\left(\frac{\sigma_0}{\sigma_1}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{\sigma_0^2}-\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} \right)\frac{(dY_t)^2}{dt} $$

Does this make sense? I was expecting to get some SDE for the posterior/likelihood but I feel there is something fishy in the expression I get. Is it possible to do optimal filtering of wiener process of unknown variance in some (other?) way?

Comment: In a formal setting you can't really use $dY_t$ and $dt$ like that. This is because SDEs are just a shorthand of stochastic integrals. You indeed end up with an ill-defined quantity ($dY_t/dt$). Best you can do to start is study $Y_{t+\Delta t}-Y_t$ for some $\Delta t >0$.

Comment: In the derivations above I used $dY$ as a shorthand for $Y_{t +dt} - Y_t$ and similarly for $\ell_t.$ These are exact derivations, no stochastic calculus.